# Android Review Manager

Tags: android

apologies in advance, I'm more of a iOS developer than Android and despite reading various tutorials I'm really struggling to create a simple Google review prompt in my app.

I'm using ReviewManagerFactory. I've adde the build.gradle dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0'
```

Within my code, on one activity I have a simple function called 'reviewPrompt'. Creating an instance of ReviewManager and requesting start review flow.

```
    private void reviewPrompt() {
    ReviewManager manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(this);
    manager.requestReviewFlow();
}
```

Is this all I need to do to achieve a review prompt? A lot of other tutorials (including Google ) keep talking about creating an instance of ReviewManagerFactory first

```
ReviewManager manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(context)
```

And then adding this:

```
ReviewManager manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(this);
Task<ReviewInfo> request = manager.requestReviewFlow();
request.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        // We can get the ReviewInfo object
        ReviewInfo reviewInfo = task.getResult();
    } else {
        // There was some problem, log or handle the error code.
        @ReviewErrorCode int reviewErrorCode = ((TaskException) task.getException()).getErrorCode();
    }
});
```

Why are they advising creating 2 instances of ReviewManger? Firstly with (context) and then with (this)? If both are needed do they both go in the same function or does

```
ReviewManager manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(context)
```

Go somewhere else??

They also seem to attach listeners etc (in various ways), but as far as I can see that isn't necessarily needed unless I wish to track whether the review flow completed or failed etc.

Please correct me if I'm missing anything here.

Finally, I wish to call this function only when a user has opened a particular activity 'x' number of times in the app's lifetime. I my iOS I used User Defaults and reviewWorthyActionCount. Is there anything similar in Android?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Anyone going to help???

Comment: I tried to answer your question but you probably did not have much luck because your question lacks detail. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Dear dominicolor, thanks for effort, however unsure what more detail I could give, have put comments under your answer

Comment: I explained all the things that need more detail. You only addressed my first point. Your question continues to lack the information I mentioned.

Comment: I did put more comments but they didn’t post for some reason. However have to agree to disagree, I provided all info needed, as seen by the other poster who’s post answered my questions. For example, you state I needed to add code about the listeners…the code is there. Thanks anyway. All the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example on the documentation is separated into 3 sections, it can be a bit hard to understand if you are new to android. Here you have a fully working example integrating the 3 sections from the documentation.

```
ReviewManager manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(this);
Task<ReviewInfo> request = manager.requestReviewFlow();
request.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        ReviewInfo reviewInfo = task.getResult();
        val flow = manager.launchReviewFlow(this@/*Your activity class name here(ie:MainActivity)*/, reviewInfo)
        flow.addOnCompleteListener { _ ->
            //do something after the review flow finishes, like logging that the review flow was completed successfully
        }
    } else {
        // There was some problem, log or handle the error code.
        @ReviewErrorCode int reviewErrorCode = ((TaskException) task.getException()).getErrorCode();
    }
});
```

**Explanation:**

Both

```
ReviewManager manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(context)
```

and

```
ReviewManager manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(this)
```

are the same thing, the second section on the documentation includes the first one, assuming that "this" is an object of type "context".

Then the line:

```
val flow = manager.launchReviewFlow(activity, reviewInfo)
```

might be confusing too, it means that the first parameter of launchReviewFlow should be of type activity, and will not work if you copy and paste the code. You will have to use something like:

```
val flow = manager.launchReviewFlow(this, reviewInfo)
//or
val flow = manager.launchReviewFlow(this@MainActivity, reviewInfo)
```

when "MainActivity" is the class name of your activity.

Then to store a counter you can use SharedPreferences or the new DataStore library as dominicoder said.

Answer (score 2):

according to [ReviewManagerFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/review/ReviewManagerFactory) , you should pass context , by the way android activity is context too . when you mention "this" it means you pass current object(the activity ) . you don't need to create 2 diffrenet objects using **this** and **context** ( both are same)

for second case , first save a value called fooActivityVisited in android SharedPereference ( its a local storage to store values) , then in your activity you increate it and check when reached to "Count" you will show the review

Answer (score 0):

> Why are they advising creating 2 instances of ReviewManger? Firstly with (context) and then with (this)? If both are needed do they both go in the same function or does
>
> ```
> ReviewManager manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(context)
> ```
>
> Go somewhere else??

Your post is lacking ... *context* (hehe) ... but I don't think they're advising creating two instances, you might be looking at two different examples. I can't tell since you posted random snippets instead of a full example.

In any case, you need to create an instance of the manager with a `Context`. In the first example it would seem the code is called from a `View` or a `Fragment` neither of which are themselves `Context`s, but they do *have a* `context` property.

In the second example, it would seem the code is called from an `Activity`, which *is a* `Context`, so it can be called with `this`.

As to where this *goes* - well, it would go wherever you need this manager object.

It would be easier to answer your question with full code examples or links to whatever tutorial you're following.

> They also seem to attach listeners etc (in various ways), but as far
> as I can see that isn't necessarily needed unless I wish to track
> whether the review flow completed or failed etc.
>
> Please correct me if I'm missing anything here.

Is there a question here? Which listeners is it that "they seem to attach"? What is this assumption based on? Can you post some code or a link to an example you're looking at?

> Finally, I wish to call this function only when a user has opened a
> particular activity 'x' number of times in the app's lifetime. I my
> iOS I used User Defaults and reviewWorthyActionCount. Is there
> anything similar in Android?

You are asking Android developers if there's anything similar to some iOS constructs without explaining what those constructs are. I could tell you if there is anything similar on Android if you explain what "User Defaults" and "reviewWorthyActionCount" are.

Beyond that, if I wanted to track some simple persistent state like "viewed Activity X times" I'd probably use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) or [the new DataStore library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore).

Comment: First part: its the same example, I clearly write the same tutorial firstly advises ReviewManager manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(context) then ReviewManager manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(this). Which is why I found this confusing.